# How to get the download url from Firebase Storage?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to get the Download Url from `uploadTask.addOnProgressListener` method of Firebase. How can I get the Download Url using following code?

```
    UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putBytes(data);

    uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
        {
            Log.d("aaaaasessin",""+taskSnapshot.getTask().getResult());
        }
    });
```

I used `taskSnapshot.getTask().getResult()` but that is not working.

Answer (score 12):

**Edit Aug 22th 2019:**

There is a new method recently added to StorageReference's class in the Android SDK named [list()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#list(int)).

To solve this, you need to loop over the `ListResult` and call `getDownloadUrl()` to get the download URLs of each file. Remember that `getDownloadUrl()` method is asynchronous, so it returns a `Task` object. See below for details. I have even written an article regarding this topic called:

- [How to upload an image to Cloud Storage and save the URL in Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46)

---

In order to get the download url, you need to use `addOnSuccessListener`, like in the following lines of code:

```
uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                String url = uri.toString();

                //Do what you need to do with url
            }
        });
    }
});
```

As in the [Firebase release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) on May 23, 2018 is mentioned that:

> Cloud Storage version 16.0.1
>
> Removed the deprecated StorageMetadata.getDownloadUrl() and UploadTask.TaskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() methods. To get a current download URL, use StorageReference.getDownloadUr().

So now when calling [getDownloadUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl()) on a [StorageReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference) object it returns a `Task` object and **not** an Uri object anymore.

Please also rememeber, neither the success listener nor the failure listener (if you intend to use it), will be called if your device cannot reach Firebase Storage backend. The success/failure listeners will only be called once the data is committed to, or rejected by the Firebase servers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but,I perform upload task offline so i can't use onSuccsess().I have to use only uploadTask.addOnProgressListener()

Comment: Yes, that's correct, `onSuccsess()` is not triggered while offile but unfortunately using `addOnSuccessListener` you cannot override `onSuccess()` method to get the download url. Which makes sense because you can only get the download url only once you get a responde from the server (onSuccess is triggered). You cannot get a download url as long as the task is not completed, right?

Comment: OK,any alternative way avilable if so please suggest me

Comment: No, there is not. You can get the download url **only** when the upload is successful, with other words when the server provides you the url. When you are offline and there is no direct connection between the device and to the server, there is no url that you can get. Can I help you with other informations?