# Profile image not showing after saving(it just shows blank white screen)

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am trying to upload user profile image and store in firebase.My image successfully stores in firebase storage and in the user database.

When I upload the image it shows on my screen,but once I save and reopen the settings to see the profile image,it does not show,it just shows blank white screen(but the name and phone show when reopened,only image does not show)

I have attached the code that gets value from db and shows in ui and also added the saveUserInformation() which is called when the user clicks the save image button and this function saves name,phone and profileimage in db. I have added screenshot of database below and also added the snippet of error I am getting.

What am I doing wrong?

This is what glide outputs when i console logged it :
profile img here:Target for: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{528bbb2 V.ED..C.. ......ID 0,0-300,300 #7f0a00b9 app:id/profileImage}[CDS]rx timeout:0

```js
 mCustomerDatabase.addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.childrenCount>0){
                    val map:Map<*,*> = dataSnapshot.value as Map<*,*>
                    if(map["name"] !=null){
                        mName=map["name"].toString()
                        mNameField.setText(mName)
                    }
                    if(map["phone"]!=null){
                        mPhone=map["phone"].toString()
                        mPhoneField.setText(mPhone)
                    }
                    if(map["profileImageUrl"]!=null){
                        mProfileImageUrl=map["profileImageUrl"].toString()

                        Glide.with(applicationContext).load(mProfileImageUrl).into(mProfileImage)
                        val a=Glide.with(applicationContext).load(mProfileImageUrl).into(mProfileImage)

                        print("profile img here:$a")

                    }

                }

            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        })
```

```js
    private fun saveUserInformation(){
        mName=mNameField.text.toString()
        mPhone=mPhoneField.text.toString()
        val userInfo=HashMap<String,Any>()
        userInfo.put("name",mName)
        userInfo.put("phone",mPhone)
        mCustomerDatabase.updateChildren(userInfo)
        if(resultUri!=null){
            val imagePath:StorageReference=mStorage.child("customer_profile_image").child(userId).child(resultUri.lastPathSegment )
            val uploadTask:UploadTask=imagePath.putFile(resultUri)
            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener <UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>(){taskSnapshot->
                    val downloadUrl: Task<Uri> =taskSnapshot.storage.downloadUrl
                    val newImage= HashMap<String,Any>()
                    newImage["profileImageUrl"] = downloadUrl.toString()
                    mCustomerDatabase.updateChildren(newImage)

            }).addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener() {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Profile image not uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            })
        }
        finish()
    }
```

```js
Load failed for com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@c0645c1 with size [300x300]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There were 3 causes:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@c0645c1: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(No such file or directory)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(No such file or directory)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@c0645c1: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@c0645c1: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: /com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@c0645c1: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
      Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(No such file or directory)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(No such file or directory)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
      Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(No such file or directory)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
02-04 15:21:14.109 25281-25281/com.sarah.taxi I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 3)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@c0645c1: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:487)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:689)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResourceFromUri(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:85)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:60)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:15)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:44)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:99)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:302)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:272)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:233)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:473)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103) 
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:689) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResourceFromUri(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:85) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:60) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:15) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:44) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:99) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:302) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:272) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:233) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446) 
02-04 15:21:14.110 25281-25281/com.sarah.taxi I/Glide: Root cause (2 of 3)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
        at android.os.Parcel.openFileDescriptor(Native Method)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:270)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:200)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:966)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:894)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.FileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(FileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:22)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.FileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(FileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:14)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:44)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:99)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:302)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:397)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:119)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:153)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:144)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:49)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:99)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:302)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:272)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:233)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
    Root cause (3 of 3)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
        at android.os.Parcel.openFileDescriptor(Native Method)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:270)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:200)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:966)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:894)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:22)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:13)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:44)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:302)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:397)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:119)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:153)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:144)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:49)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:99)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:302)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:397)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:119)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:153)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:144)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:49)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:99)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:302)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:272)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:233)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh5OQ.png)

Comment: Please also add the code that you are using to add the `profileImageUrl` to the database.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the code used to add profileImageUrl to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> Load failed for com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@c0645c1

Because you are trying to display an image that does not exist. As I see in your database, the `profileImageUrl` property holds an image url that is **not** valid.

[image]

See the red line? What it actually holds is the address of an object from the memory and **not** an image url. This is happening because you are calling `toString()` method on the `downloadUrl` object. So the way you are get the donwload url is not correct. **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-offline-uploded-file-download-url-in-firebase/53300660#53300660)** is the correct way for getting the url. Once you get url of the image and you add it to the database and everything will work as expected.

Comment: I changed my code as you mentioned and it was the download url problem,now it works.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and solved the problem as follows

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
       .fitCenter()
       .error(errorImageDrawble)
       .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
       .priority(priority.HIGH);

Glide
     .with(applicationContext)
     .load(mProfileImageUrl)
     .apply(options)
     .into(mProfileImage);
```

Comment: I tried adding requestoptions,but it did not work, I still see no image and am getting the same error which I have added above in question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function in which I updated the imagePath listener code which works fine now-

```js
private fun saveUserInformation(){
        mName=mNameField.text.toString()
        mPhone=mPhoneField.text.toString()
        val userInfo=HashMap<String,Any>()
        userInfo.put("name",mName)
        userInfo.put("phone",mPhone)
        mCustomerDatabase.updateChildren(userInfo)
        if(resultUri!=null){
            val imagePath:StorageReference=mStorage.child("customer_profile_image").child(userId).child(resultUri.lastPathSegment )
            val uploadTask:UploadTask=imagePath.putFile(resultUri)

            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener <UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>(){taskSnapshot->

 //*********************This is the upadated part of code                   imagePath.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<Uri>{resultUri->
                        val downloadUrl=resultUri.toString()
                        val newImage= HashMap<String,Any>()
                        newImage["profileImageUrl"] = downloadUrl
                        mCustomerDatabase.updateChildren(newImage)
                    }).addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener() {
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Profile image not",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    })
//*******************************************************************************


            }).addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener() {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Profile image not uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            })
        }
        finish()
    }
```