# Unable to download images from FireBase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make an android app which can upload images to firebase and retrieve it. The uploading is happening perfectly , but I am unable to retrieve the images. I am able to retrieve the text which i attach to the image , but not the download image itself. I am using glide library to get the images from firebase which will then be displayed in a recycler view.

EDIT

[Question referred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54512029/profile-image-not-showing-after-savingit-just-shows-blank-white-screen)  Here the top answer tell you you to add an `addOnSuccessListener` to the storageReference. But I have already done that in ImageSelect.java class

Code for RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<ImageUploadInfo> MainImageUploadInfoList;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ImageUploadInfo> TempList) {

    this.MainImageUploadInfoList = TempList;

    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ImageUploadInfo UploadInfo = MainImageUploadInfoList.get(position);

    holder.imageNameTextView.setText(UploadInfo.getImageName());
    //Loading image from Glide library.
    Glide.with(context).load(UploadInfo.getImageURL()).into(holder.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return MainImageUploadInfoList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView imageNameTextView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        imageNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageNameTextView);
    }
}
}
```

The output Im getting:

[image]

Code for ImageSelect.java class

Please help me to solve the problem of mine.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_select);

    // Assign FirebaseStorage instance to storageReference.
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    // Assign FirebaseDatabase instance with root database name.
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Database_Path);

    // Assigning Id to ProgressDialog.
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ImageSelect.this);

    clickedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
    caption = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caption);
    slidr = Slidr.attach(this);

    if(CameraActivity.i == "1"  )
    {
        //Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
       // byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("bytearray");
        // bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
        //String setter = bundle.getString("setter");
        imageUri = getIntent().getData();
        clickedImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }

    else {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);

        File f = new File(photoPath);
        imageUri = getIntent().getData();

        clickedImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }

    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            UploadImageFileToFirebaseStorage();
        }
    });

}

// Creating Method to get the selected image file Extension from File Path URI.
public String GetFileExtension(Uri uri) {

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();

    // Returning the file Extension.
    return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri)) ;

}


// Creating UploadImageFileToFirebaseStorage method to upload image on storage.
public void UploadImageFileToFirebaseStorage(){

    // Setting progressDialog Title.
    progressDialog.setTitle("Image is Uploading...");

    // Showing progressDialog.
    progressDialog.show();

    // Creating second StorageReference.
    StorageReference storageReference2nd = storageReference.child(Storage_Path + System.currentTimeMillis() + "."  +GetFileExtension(imageUri));

    // Adding addOnSuccessListener to second StorageReference.
    storageReference2nd.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    // Getting image name from EditText and store into string variable.
                    String TempImageName = caption.getText().toString().trim();

                    // Hiding the progressDialog after done uploading.
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    // Showing toast message after done uploading.
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Uploaded Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                    ImageUploadInfo imageUploadInfo = new ImageUploadInfo(TempImageName, taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString().toString());

                    // Getting image upload ID.
                    String ImageUploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();

                    // Adding image upload id s child element into databaseReference.
                    databaseReference.child(ImageUploadId).setValue(imageUploadInfo);
                }
            })
            // If something goes wrong .
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

                    // Hiding the progressDialog.
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    // Showing exception erro message.
                    Toast.makeText(ImageSelect.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })

            // On progress change upload time.
            .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    // Setting progressDialog Title.
                    progressDialog.setTitle("Image is Uploading...");

                }
            });
}

}
```

Comment: What is the value of `UploadInfo.getImageName()`? Please also add your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo `UploadInfo.getImageName()` is the string that I store along with the image. In the above output image its the Test label

Comment: Sorry, what is the value of `UploadInfo.getImageURL()` ? Please also add your database structure.

Comment: The value of `UploadInfo.getImageURL()` is `URL = com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@d7c298e`

Comment: And i dont understand what database structure means as im new to firebase and android programming