# How to fetch all URLs from Firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

Is there any way to fetch all the URLs from Firebase Storage?

[image]

I know there are ways to fetch URLs from firebase database like storing URLs of Firebase Storage files in Firebase Realtime Database and fetch from it. But I am uploading images from the button which is showing in the image and want URLs of all those uploaded images directly from the firebase storage path like...

```
var mStorageRef: StorageReference

mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
```

and using it something like...

```
mStorageRef.fetchall() or mStorageRef.getall()
```

I also foudn [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?authuser=0) link where you can downlaod files by its name and only one by one. I want a way to fetch all at once.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-offline-uploaded-file-download-url-in-firebase/53300660#53300660)** out.

Comment: You need to add the URL's of those images in your database and then fetch those database values

Comment: @Alex Mamo I am uploading using button and not by code

Comment: Version 6.1 of the Firebase JavaScript SDK added the ability to list files: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#storage. For other platforms you'll have to do what Alex and Doug said, and what I also included in my linked answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no provided API that lets you do this.

What you can do instead is use a Cloud Function that triggers on the creation of a new object in Cloud Storage, then have it create a signed URL.  Store that URL in a database somewhere, then query the database when you need those URLs.

Comment: awesome, thanks! Looking forward to a more better way