# can we use both Cloud Storage and Cloud Firestore databases for a single project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I would like to use the firestore for my actual data and firebase storage for storing the images.

Can i use firbese and firestore for the same project ?

Comment: Cloud Storage and Cloud Firestore are different products that solve different problems, and you should use them each to address the specific needs of your app where they are best suited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @M.Ali mentioned in answer, yes you can use both services in a single project. As an addition, I would like to say that we use Cloud Firestore and Firebase Storage together, in the moment when we need to keep a reference of a file for a later use. For instance, let's say you want to add a .PDF file with some recommendations in Firebase Storage. Once you have [successfully add it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-offline-uploaded-file-download-url-in-firebase/53300660#53300660), you can then simply add that `url` to Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Answer. YES you can!

Most apps use **Firestore** for realtime database and **Storage** for storing images, audios, and any large files