# Firestore/Firebase not able to get images from folder

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

**I have a folder on firebase. which named 'Item'. 'Item' contains 100 images. I just want to fetch just all images Url in the list.

 I have tried google documents. Google showing only for a single image. But I just need complete images URLs.**

```
 FirebaseStorage firestore = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
 val ref: StorageReference? = firestore.getReference("Item")


I am facing this error =
StorageException has occurred. The object​ does not exist at the  location
```

[image]

Comment: @AlexMamo: I reopened this question. While getting the download URL is needed to implement this use-case, there's a lot more to it, hence it's not a exact duplicate.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You're right puf, makes more sense to remain open 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i found in documentation this method could help `public Task<ListResult> listAll ()`

First you need to get needed reference of the folder in your case it is item/

```
StorageReference mImageStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("items/");
```

And then with help of `listAll()` inflate the list of files in it

Here is the description 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#listAll()

Comment: firestore = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                val ref: StorageReference? = firestore.getReference("Item/")
              ref?.listAll()?.addOnSuccessListener {

                  val item = it.items
                   list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
                   list.adapter = Adapter(activity, item)
               }

Comment: It's working, thanks. I have done. This is the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `firestore.getReference("Item")`, which gives you a `StorageReference` to that folder. The Android, iOS and JavaScript SDKs of Firebase recently added a method to [list the files in a folder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#list(int)) to `StorageReference`.

So you need to loop over the `ListResult` and call `getDownloadUrl` to get the download URL for each file. Keep min mind that `getDownloadUrl` is asynchronous, so it returns a task. Get the actual download URL as shown here: [How to get the download url from Firebase Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-the-download-url-from-firebase-storage)

Comment: It is also the correct answer. Thanks, Frank van Puffelen