# Uploading two files on firebase in callback but unable to getDownloadUrl of both files

Tags: java, android, firebase, callback, firebase-storage

I'm uploading two files from an array on Firebase storage and want to get getDownloadUrl of both files but it returns only first element's uri. In this code `mThumbUri` is always empty.

```
public class UploadingService extends JobIntentService implements UploadCallBacks {
private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "upload_channel";
private static final int JOB_ID = 1000;
private HashMap<String, String> values;

String mVideoUri = "";
String mThumbUri = "";
private FirebaseUser mUser;
private String postId = null;
//Firebase
StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent intent) {
    enqueueWork(context, UploadingService.class, JOB_ID, intent);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    createNotificationChannel();
    mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

}
@Override
protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
    if (intent.hasExtra(AppConstants.DATA)) {
        values = (HashMap<String, String>) intent.getSerializableExtra(AppConstants.DATA);
        hitVideoUploadApi();
    }
}

/**
 * method for video upload
 */
private void hitVideoUploadApi() {
    postId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<>();
    Uri VideoUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(values.get(AppConstants.VIDEO_PATH)));
    Uri ThumbUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(values.get(AppConstants.THUMB_PATH)));

    files.add(VideoUri);
    files.add(ThumbUri);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Using a loop I'm upload both files on firebase storage and getting url in string **mVideoUrl** and **mThumbUrl** to upload these string to firebaseDatabase:

```
final int[] i = {0};
    for (Uri uri : files) {

        storageRef.child("PostData/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()).putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
             Task<Uri> uri = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {

                        Uri uri = task.getResult();
                        i[0]++;
                        if (i[0] == 1) {
                            mVideoUri = uri.toString();

                        } else {
                            mThumbUri = uri.toString();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Here in addOnCompleteListener calling a fun to upload thse urls to firebase Realtime database

```
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                hitUploadPostApi(mVideoUri, mThumbUri, postId);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error while Uploading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that the task is successful? You should add a condition `if (task.isSuccessfull())` in your `onComplete` callbacks to make sure you are not proceeding with error.

Comment: In which place do you say that `mThumbUri` is empty? Inside the `onComplete` method?

Comment: yea it task is working successfully and uploading both files but getting getDownloadUrl just  of first file which is mVideoUrl @Christilyn

Comment: `Uri uri = task.getResult();
                        i[0]++;
                        if (i[0] == 1) {
                            mVideoUri = uri.toString();

                        } else {
                            mThumbUri = uri.toString();
                        }`
here in else **uri.tostring**  is empty which i'm storing in**mThumbUri** @AlexMamo

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-offline-uploaded-file-download-url-in-firebase/53300660#53300660)** is the way you should get the download url.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do once the upload is complete you can check the firebase storage to get all the URL of files considering you know the names of the file.
I wrote this 1 year back and it worked then.

[image]

inside the [child()] method you have to put the name of the file.
Also, remember firebase is asynchronous.

Now coming to your code what I think is causing the problem is

Initially
i[0]=0;
1 file upload complete successfully
i[0]=1,
2 file upload complete successfully
i[0]=2.

But you are checking
[if(i[0]==1)] {whereas 2nd time 'i' is two}

Comment: if (i[0] == 1)  works when i++ and for 2nd file i have used else{ ....} so it should workif i is 0 or 2

Comment: Hi Rohan. Please replace your image with the text equivalant - if someone wishes to you your code, they won't want to transcribe it from the image. Thanks!