# Glide not loading images while working with firebase cloud

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

So , I am working on small chat application that can load images stored in Firebase cloud.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // Code for text message
    }
        else if(requestCode==RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Uri selectedImageUri=data.getData();
            StorageReference photoRef=mChatPhotoReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
            photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    String downloadUrl=taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                    FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage=new FriendlyMessage(null,mUsername,downloadUrl);
                    mDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                    Log.e("WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",downloadUrl);

                }
            });
    }

}
```

and here is get view .

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_message, parent, false);
    }

    ImageView photoImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
    TextView messageTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
    TextView authorTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);

    FriendlyMessage message = getItem(position);
```

//FriendlyMessage is class that stores text , username and image url

```
    boolean isPhoto = message.getPhotoUrl() != null;
    if (isPhoto) {
        Log.e("VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV",message.getPhotoUrl());
        messageTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        photoImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Glide.with(photoImageView.getContext())
                .load(message.getPhotoUrl())
                .into(photoImageView);
    } else {
          Load text..
    }
    authorTextView.setText(message.getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

I a am using

`glidle : 4.11.0
firebase-storage:19.1.0`

Comment: Please check if you're receiving `message.getPhotoUrl()` value inside

Comment: @Ashish Yes , I looged it  and getting correct value.

Comment: @AmanSharma try to open that in browser

Comment: @frankenstein , they are unlike webadresses , they are specific references inside cloud storage example : com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@d4cf139

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the download url from Firebase Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-the-download-url-from-firebase-storage)

Comment: @AmanSharma That is a java object

Comment: @AmanSharma that's why glide not able to access. You need url like this `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxApp.appspot.com/o/logo.png?alt=media&token=c0472xxxxxxxxx88c44` .And it required `Token`.

Comment: thanx @frankenstein , Indeed the Url which i was using was actually java object as pointed out by _jake , However after using the referred Post , i was able to store correct URL it.

Comment: @jake , yeah that post did work .

Answer (score 1):

Try with RequestOptions all should looks like

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                    .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);



 Glide.with(this)
    .load(image_url)
    .apply(options)
    .into(imageView);
```

If you doesn't get url you will display error images, in this case ic_lanucher_round

Comment: I did that and icon is not displayed . However i logged urls and they are of form com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@d4cf1xx

Comment: try to change inside get view to something like that `if (convertView == null) {
            final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_message, false);
        }`

Comment: solved it , the problem was : taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl() returned task object instead of Uri @kyluAce

Answer (score 1):

The url you are receiving doesnt contain image, its still uploading there.
You need to do something like this.
Here while loop will make it wait, until image is uploaded completely.

```
 storageRef.child(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).putFile(uri)
                .addOnSuccessListener { p0 ->
                    val downloadUrl = p0!!.storage.downloadUrl
                    @Suppress("ControlFlowWithEmptyBody")
                    while (!downloadUrl.isSuccessful);

                    try {
                        val imagePath = downloadUrl.result!!.toString()
}
```

its in Kotlin, you can translate easily.

Comment: But the images are being displayed correct when i check it through website.

Comment: The url you are trying to get is not correct to display, try getting it the way i'm getting and then it'll be displayed correctly in your app.