# Android Glide: Failed to load resource of Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I'm trying to display the image in CircularImageView stored in Firebase Storage, but glide gives me this error:

```
W/Glide: Load failed for gs://project-2d8i4.appspot.com/pictures/3HnfQSeBladDsD9sPEcKrhxJ6CB2 with size [1200x1200]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
```

The picture is saved in Firestore as:

```
"gs://project-2d8i4.appspot.com/pictures/3HnfQSeBladDsD9sPEcKrhxJ6CB2"
```

Binding to image view `(uri = "gs://project-2d8i4.appspot.com/pictures/3HnfQSeBladDsD9sPEcKrhxJ6CB2")`:

```
fun CircularImageView.bindProfilePicture(uri: String?) {
    Glide
        .with(this)
        .load(uri)
        .into(this)
}
```

Dependencies for glide:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
```

No answers in any posts helped me whatsoever. I hope someone could help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following URL:

```
gs://project-2d8i4.appspot.com/pictures/3HnfQSeBladDsD9sPEcKrhxJ6CB
```

Is indeed a file that is stored in Cloud Storage. Unfortunately, this URL is not recognized by Glide, as it is not a valid URL. To solve the problem you need to get the "download URL" rather than an URL that starts with `gs://...`.

To get the actual download URL, please see the official documentation for:

- [How to create a reference to a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url)

And my answer from the following post:

- [How to get the download url from Firebase Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-offline-uploaded-file-download-url-in-firebase/53300660#53300660)

Comment: Hi, thanks. Whenever I upload the picture even with the same ID to the storage, downloadUrl changes all the time, which is great. It helps me with the real-time solutions.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid cache as mentioned in comments, you can use these two along with glide call.

```
diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE) 
.skipMemoryCache(true)
```

Check [here](https://medium.com/@egemenhamutcu/displaying-images-from-firebase-storage-using-glide-for-kotlin-projects-3e4950f6c103) to use the glide to download from firebase url.

Comment: Do I need to download that file to local storage? Because I receive the same error and additionally `java.io.IOException(File unsuitable for memory mapping)`. If looking at Firebase documentation, when using FirebaseUI I simply need to pass the reference to that file - it's what I did.

Comment: My bad, if you can check here : https://medium.com/@egemenhamutcu/displaying-images-from-firebase-storage-using-glide-for-kotlin-projects-3e4950f6c103

Comment: Great. It does get load, but when I update my storage with different pic using same ID, and then GlideApp gets that picture under that ID, it always returns first picture that I uploaded. How is this possible? Is this getting cached on my phone or what?

Comment: Use these two methods along with your above glide code.

.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
.skipMemoryCache(true)

Comment: Is it a good idea to use those two? Actually, by using Alex's answer I can use catching and also the downloadUrl changes all the time whenever I change storage's pic even with the same ID. Thanks for the help.