# Firebase recyclerview images disappear after reload application

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

When I just added it, everything is fine, but when I restart the application, only textViews is displayed. There is an empty space instead of an imageView.

My recycler adapter:

```
 class PersonAdapter(options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Outfit?>) :
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Outfit, personsViewHolder>(options) {


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: personsViewHolder, position: Int, model: Outfit) {
      
        holder.name.text = model.name
        holder.brand.text = model.brand
        holder.size.text = model.size
        holder.comment.text = model.comment
        holder.price.text = model.price
        Picasso.get().load(model.imageUrl).into(holder.imageView) //Glide analog

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): personsViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false)
        return personsViewHolder(view)
    }
  
    class personsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var name: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name_value)
        var brand: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_brand_value)
        var size: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_size_value)
        var comment: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_comment_value)
        var price: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_price_value)
        var imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView)

    }

}
```

Class what add to database:

```
    private var dataBase: DatabaseReference? = null
    private lateinit var outfitImage: ImageView
    private var imageUri: Uri? = null

    private var id: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_outfit)

        nameView = findViewById(R.id.et_outfitName)
        brandView = findViewById(R.id.et_outfitBrand)
        sizeView = findViewById(R.id.et_outfitSize)
        commentView = findViewById(R.id.et_outfitComment)
        priceView = findViewById(R.id.et_outfitPrice)

        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btn_addOutfit)
        btnLoad = findViewById(R.id.btn_load)


        btnAdd?.setOnClickListener {
            onClickSave()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Added to database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
        }
        btnLoad?.setOnClickListener {
            onClickRead()
        }

        outfitImage = findViewById(R.id.iv_upload_image)
        outfitImage.setOnClickListener {
            chooseImage()
        }


    }
    //SAVE BUTTON
    private fun onClickSave() {


        dataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(UUID.randomUUID().toString())

        dataBase?.setValue(
            Outfit(
                nameView?.text.toString(),
                brandView?.text.toString(),
                sizeView?.text.toString(),
                commentView?.text.toString(),
                priceView?.text.toString(),
                imageUri.toString()
            )
        )
        uploadImageToFirebase(imageUri!!)
    }


    //----------------UPLOAD IMAGE-----------------------
    private fun chooseImage() {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.type = "image/*"
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Please select..."), 1
        )
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.data != null) {

            // Get the Uri of data
            imageUri = data.data
            outfitImage.setImageURI(imageUri)
        }
    }

    private fun uploadImageToFirebase(imageUri: Uri) {

        val pd: ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
        pd.setTitle("Uploading image...")
        pd.show()

        val fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val refStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images/$fileName")

        refStorage.putFile(imageUri)
            .addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
                taskSnapshot.storage.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                    pd.dismiss()
                    Snackbar.make(
                        findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                        "Image uploaded.",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                    )
                    val imageUrl = it.toString()

                }
            }

            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                print(e.message)
                pd.dismiss()
            }
            //progressbar
            .addOnProgressListener {
                var progressPercents: Double = (100.00 * it.bytesTransferred / it.totalByteCount)
                pd.setMessage("Percentage: $progressPercents%")
            }
    }
}
```

Logic at MainActivity:

```
mbase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler1)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Outfit>()
            .setQuery(mbase!!, Outfit::class.java)
            .build()
        // Connecting object of required Adapter class to the Adapter class itself
        adapter = PersonAdapter(options)
        // Connecting Adapter class with the Recycler view*/
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this)
```

Here are screenshots of how everything looks in the backend:
[my backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWxZM.png)

[images storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKdJh.png)

Comment: The first time you open the app does it work? For me, that "content://com.android..." doesn't look like a normal URL.

Comment: That link what database shows me, like this: gs://doyouknowkoko-59b8c.appspot.com/images/6bcf6df1-e044-4ec9-8084-8aaf29f7f924
What i need to do?

Comment: You need to use [the download URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-offline-uploaded-file-download-url-in-firebase/53300660#53300660).

Answer (score 0):

```
 private fun uploadToFirebase() {
        val pd: ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
        pd.setTitle("Uploading image...")
        pd.show()
        val fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val refStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/images/$fileName")

        refStorage.putFile(selectedPhotoUri!!)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                    pd.dismiss() //close loading
                    refStorage.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {

                        saveDataToDatabase(it.toString()) //get downloading url
                    }
                }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                print(e.message)
                pd.dismiss()
            }
            //progressbar
            .addOnProgressListener {
                var progressPercents: Double = (100.00 * it.bytesTransferred / it.totalByteCount)
                pd.setMessage("Percentage: $progressPercents%")
            }
    }

    private fun saveDataToDatabase(imageUrl:String) {
        dataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(UUID.randomUUID().toString())

        dataBase?.setValue(
            Outfit(
                nameView?.text.toString(),
                brandView?.text.toString(),
                sizeView?.text.toString(),
                commentView?.text.toString(),
                priceView?.text.toString(),
                imageUrl
            )
        )
    }
```

Here is my solution. Bad url was a ploblem.