# Problem in download Imageuri in Firebase Storage Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm uploading images from my app and storing the download URL in a model class but after I see the URL I copied it and paste the link but it didn't open up the image.

Here is the Firebase Realtime Database image
[image]

Here is the Firebase Storage
[image]

and here what it should be
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp-not-final.appspot.com/o/uploads%2F1618234721167.jpg?alt=media&token=fcac1404-87ce-4c7d-ae5f-a1ec7074bf04

**Java Files**

*Upload_Fragment.java*

```
public class Upload_Fragment extends Fragment {
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 10;
    private ImageView uploadImageView;
    private Uri mImageUri;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private StorageTask mUploadTask;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload, container, false);
        Button chooseImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.upload_image_button);
        Button uploadImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.done_button);
        uploadImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.upload_image_view);
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = storage.getReference("uploads");
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        chooseImageButton.setOnClickListener(v -> openFileChooser());
        uploadImageButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (mUploadTask != null && mUploadTask.isInProgress()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Upload in Progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                uploadToFirebase(mImageUri);
            }


        });

        return view;
    }

    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            mImageUri = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(mImageUri).into(uploadImageView);

        }
    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
    }

    private void uploadToFirebase(Uri mImageUri) {
        if (mImageUri != null) {
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();

            StorageReference reference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));
            reference.putFile(mImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Saved Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        reference.getDownloadUrl()
                                .addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                                    Upload upload = new Upload(mImageUri.toString());
                                    String uploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                                    databaseReference.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                                });
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(snapshot -> {
                        double progress = (100.0 * snapshot.getBytesTransferred() / snapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + (int) progress + "%");
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Ocurred" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    });


        }
    }
}
```

*Upload.java* *// This is the model class*

```
public class Upload {
    private String mImageUrl;


    public Upload() {

    }

    public Upload(String imageUrl) {
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getmImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setmImageUrl(String mImageUrl) {
        this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the log? It will help us to give the exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `uploadToFirebase` method inside

`reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {.....`

instead of `mImageUri.toString()` put `uri.toString()` as per bellow.So you will get actual url and will solve your problem.

```
private void uploadToFirebase(Uri mImageUri) {
        if (mImageUri != null) {
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();

            StorageReference reference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));
            reference.putFile(mImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Saved Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        reference.getDownloadUrl()
                                .addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                                    Upload upload = new Upload(uri.toString());
                                    String uploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                                    databaseReference.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                                });
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(snapshot -> {
                        double progress = (100.0 * snapshot.getBytesTransferred() / snapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + (int) progress + "%");
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Ocurred" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    });


        }
    }
```

Comment: it solved my problem but i want to ask a thing if I change mImageUrl to uri then what changes do i have to do in the model class so I can later retrieve the images

Comment: No need to do any changes in model class.Here ```mImageUri.toString()``` will give you image content address while you need https address of image so  you can get it by ```uri.toString()``` and also retrieve image with this same url.

Comment: i can't see any images in a recycler view can u please help me with this also, here is the StackOverflow link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67073457/images-not-showing-in-recyclerview-from-firebase

Answer (score 0):

In your database schema, your "mImageUrl" property holds a URL similar to this:

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents...
```

As you probably see, those URLs are pointing to some files that are located locally on the external storage. So you cannot use such URLs and expect to read data from Firebase Storage. To check the URL of an image in the Firebase Console, please see on the right-hand side a section called "File location". If you click on the token you'll get a copy of the URL of the image that looks similar to this:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp-not-final.appspot.com/...
```

This means that this is the correct URL that should be stored in the database and **not** the local one. To get the download URL please check my answer from the following post:

- [How to get the download url from Firebase Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-offline-uploaded-file-download-url-in-firebase/53300660#53300660)

Once you have the correct URL, add it to Firestore so it can be later used.