# Images not showing in recyclerview from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to get images from firebase into a recyclerview but it doesn't show up I have stored the download URL in a model class so I can retrieve it later

**Here is the screen with no images in recyclerview**
[image]

**here is the realtimedatabe screenshot**
[image]

and also the rules are true for realtimedatabase and storage

**Java Files**

*Search_Fragment.java*

```
 public class Search_Fragment extends Fragment {
    public List<Upload> mUploads;
    PostAdapter postsAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
        RecyclerView postRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.postRecyclerView);
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
        );
        mUploads = new ArrayList<>();
        postsAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), mUploads);
        postRecyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);

        //This are images that i tried manual ly and it worked fine
//        List<PostItem> postItems = new ArrayList<>();
//        postItems.add(new PostItem(R.drawable.image1));
//        postItems.add(new PostItem(R.drawable.image2));
//        postItems.add(new PostItem(R.drawable.image3));
//        postItems.add(new PostItem(R.drawable.image4));
//        postItems.add(new PostItem(R.drawable.image5));
//        postItems.add(new PostItem(R.drawable.image7));
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Upload upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                        Log.i("Sucess",upload.getmImageUrl());
                        mUploads.add(upload);

                }

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                //notify the adapter
                postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

*PostAdapter.Java //Apadter Class*

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {
    public static List<Upload> mUploads;
    Context mcontext;


    public PostAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
        mUploads = uploads;
        mcontext = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.post_item_container, parent, false);
        return new PostViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
        Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
                .borderColor(Color.WHITE)
                .borderWidthDp(5)
                .cornerRadiusDp(13)
                .oval(false)
                .build();
        Log.i("sucess",uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl());
        Picasso.get()
                .load(uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl())
                .fit()
                .transform(transformation)
                .into(holder.postImageView);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }

    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        RoundedImageView postImageView;

        PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            postImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagePost);
        }

    }
}
```

*Upload_Fragment.Java*

```
public class Upload_Fragment extends Fragment {
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 10;
    private ImageView uploadImageView;
    private Uri mImageUri;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private StorageTask mUploadTask;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload, container, false);
        Button chooseImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.upload_image_button);
        Button uploadImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.done_button);
        uploadImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.upload_image_view);
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        chooseImageButton.setOnClickListener(v -> openFileChooser());
        uploadImageButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (mUploadTask != null && mUploadTask.isInProgress()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Upload in Progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                uploadToFirebase(mImageUri);
            }


        });

        return view;
    }

    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            mImageUri = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(mImageUri).into(uploadImageView);

        }
    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
    }

    private void uploadToFirebase(Uri mImageUri) {
        if (mImageUri != null) {
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();

            StorageReference reference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));
            reference.putFile(mImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Saved Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        reference.getDownloadUrl()
                                .addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                                    Upload upload = new Upload(uri.toString());
                                    String uploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                                    databaseReference.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                                    Log.i("Link", uri.toString());
                                });
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(snapshot -> {
                        double progress = (100.0 * snapshot.getBytesTransferred() / snapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + (int) progress + "%");
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Ocurred" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    });


        }
    }
}
```

*Upload.Java //Model class*

```
public class Upload {
    private String mImageUrl;


    public Upload() {

    }

    public Upload(String imageUrl) {
        this.mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getmImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setmImageUrl(String mImageUrl) {
        this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: First Check, the url of image is right or wrong using log.

Comment: @KashyapRathod i have checked the url its correct

Comment: Inside `onDataChange `  write one `if(snapshot.exists()) {....put for loop here and success toast} else {..put toast of failure}` and share which toast is executing.

Comment: @PurveshDodiya i have did what u tell and it shows the success toast but not images

Comment: @PurveshDodiya This what i have done
               ` if (snapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Upload upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                        mUploads.add(upload);
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  }
                }
                else {
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
                //notify the adapter
                postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See to resolve your issue it needs to be debug few things then and then only you will able to resolve the issue.Also you need to clarify at which point what happen.You can try below things to get solution.

1..Put `Log` or `Toast` inside `for loop` while adding url to the `mUploads` list.Like toasting `upload.getmImageUrl()` and check is it giving you right http image url or not.

2.Put `Log` or `Toast` before the loading image url by Picasso.Like toasting `uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl()` and check is it giving you right http image url or not.

If error occuerd while toasting this put `toString();` at the end. After that you will get better idea to resolve the issue.

***EDIT:***
In above all case if you are getting right url then the problem is with `Picasso` library.You can try `Glide` to load the image.For that add

`implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'`

`annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'`

and then in side `onBindViewHolder` load image like this.

`Glide.with(mContext).load(uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl()).into(holder.postImageView);`

Comment: Im getting all the image uri  Log.i("sucess",uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl());
        Picasso.get()
                .load(uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl())
                .fit()
                .transform(transformation)
                .into(holder.postImageView); log // I/sucess: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp-not-final.appspot.com/o/uploads%2F1618318419749.jpg?alt=media&token=891962e9-51ab-42f4-aecf-126c7d58c75e

Comment: @SagarRawal I have edited answer. Please check.

Comment: OMG Thank you so much that the simplest thing that I have to do and I'm stuck it for the last 10 days straight it worked thank you so much

Comment: @SagarRawal is it worked?If yes than don't forget to upvote and accept the ans.

Answer (score 0):

```
Picasso.get()
         .load(uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl())
         .fit()
         .transform(transformation)
         .into(holder.postImageView);
```

you can try this.. maybe?

```
Picasso.with(holder.postImageView)//or context
        .load(uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl())
        .fit()
        .transform(transformation)
        .into(holder.postImageView);
```

Comment: I tried but implementing.with instead of .get gives me an error it says cannot resolve method with in Picasso