# How to upload 2 images on firebase storage on click with URL in firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

So I want to upload cover photo if user chosen or profile image if chosen on save `btn` clicked
here is my UI design for better understanding.

[image desc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrKmA.png)

for choosing image from gallery I did something like this:

```
    private void chooseImage(int imgReqCode) {
    // Defining Implicit Intent to mobile gallery
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(
                    intent,
                    "Select Image from here..."),
            imgReqCode);
}
```

and this is onActivityResult code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    checkAndSetImage(requestCode, COVER_IMG_REQUEST, resultCode, data, binding.coverPhoto, coverUri);
    checkAndSetImage(requestCode, PROFILE_IMG_REQUEST, resultCode, data, binding.profilePhoto, profileUri);
}
```

And this is my `checkAndSetImage` method :

```
private void checkAndSetImage(int requestCode, int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST, int resultCode, Intent data, ImageView imageView, Uri filePath) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        // Get the Uri of data
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            // Setting image on image view using Bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log the exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And this is my Uri 's which is declare as global :

```
private Uri coverUri, profileUri;
```

**After that I am confused How can I upload that to firebase storage** and get both or which is available's url in my **firestore database**

or According to you how can you upload 2 Images (1. Cover, 2. Profile) in firebase database accoriding to my layout

[image desc according to my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrKmA.png)

Comment: This is how you get the [download URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-offline-uploaded-file-download-url-in-firebase/53300660#53300660) of the image you have uploaded to Firebase Storage.

Comment: @AlexMamo u are right but how can I achive that in my case  or I want two upload to images and both's URL should be uploaded on firestore. any help please.

Comment: Create two separate Storage addition operations.

Comment: @AlexMamo I will try

Comment: Ok, give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: @JackSparrow please let us know if the above comment helps you.

Comment: @RajeevTirumalasetty Yeah! it helps me.

Comment: @AlexMamo can you please post your comment as an answer for visibility?

Comment: @JackSparrow Just did. Good to hear you solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can upload the `coverUri` and the `profileUri` pictures in parallel and expect to complete the upload at the same time. What you have to do is to create two separate uploads, and once the upload URL is available, write it to Firestore. Please check below how you can get the download URL in Java:

- [How to get the download url from Firebase Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-the-download-url-from-firebase-storage/53300660#53300660)

Comment: why not ..........................