# How to download Firebasee Realtime Database image/data. Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-download-manager

I have data/images from Firebase Realtime Database that is displayed in a recyclerview. In that recyclerview I placed a button that will allow users to download whatever image they choose. I ran the code and pressed the button, but nothing happened.

**Code**

```
class AbstractAdapter(private val mContext: Context, private val abstractList: List<Abstract>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<AbstractAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.abstract_image_view, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {


    holder.download_btn.setOnClickListener {
        downloadFile()

    }

    Glide.with(mContext)
        .load(abstractList[position].abstract)
        .into(holder.imageView)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return abstractList.size
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.abstractImageView)
    val download_btn: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.abstractDownloadBtn)


}

private fun downloadFile() {
    val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    val storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("https://notes-72413.firebaseio.com/")
    val islandRef = storageRef.child("abstract")
    val rootPath = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "file_name")
    if (!rootPath.exists()) {
        rootPath.mkdirs()
    }
    val localFile = File(rootPath, "imageName.txt")
    islandRef.getFile(localFile)
        .addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot?> {
            Log.e("firebase ", ";local tem file created  created " + localFile.toString())
            //  updateDb(timestamp,localFile.toString(),position);
        }).addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.e(
                "firebase ",
                ";local tem file not created  created $exception"
            )
        })
}

companion object {
    private const val Tag = "RecyclerView"
}
```

**My logcat error**

```
 Firebase Storage URLs must point to an object in your Storage Bucket. Please obtain a URL using the Firebase Console or getDownloadUrl()
```

[image: Here's a screenshot for a reference of what my layout looks like]

Comment: Is any log statements printed out in the logcat?

Comment: Nothing shows. I edited my code, but now the app crashes when I press the button

Comment: Then is your onSuccess or onFailure even called?

Comment: They aren't called. No. They are only called in my main fragment class as that is the class that's responsible for showing my firebase realtime data base data.

Comment: What is the code that works?

Comment: Everything except the download() function

Comment: Are you sure there is a correct file a that location?

Comment: I put the correct link for Firebase ref and child path

Comment: This is the error the logcat gives me:  Firebase Storage URLs must point to an object in your Storage Bucket. Please obtain a URL using the Firebase Console or getDownloadUrl()

Comment: Most likely you're looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-offline-uploaded-file-download-url-in-firebase/), right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245425/discussion-between-kwezi-mashapa-and-alex-mamo).